# how can i send information from composite to entrypoint class?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

my problem is about my GWT project.
i got 2 files named Main.java(EntryPoint) and Registration.java(Composite) in my client package. Registration class is just user interface for registration.(it has text boxes and button)

There is a register button in Registration class which takes all information from registration form. My problem is here. how can i send this information from Registration class to EntryPoint class when user clicks button?

this is my onModuleLoad method;

....

Registration registration =  new Registration();

```
     dockLayoutPanel.add(registration);
```

....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Command Pattern, for example I also have an Interface

```
public interface SuperPuperHandler<T> {
  public void onFire(T t);
}
```

and in your Registration class add save handler:

```
  public class Registration extends Composite{
       private SuperPuperHandler<MySavedObject> saveHandler;

       public void addSaveHandler(SuperPuperHandler<MySavedObject> saveHandler){
          this.saveHandler=saveHandler;
       }

       .....
       savebutton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
           public void onClick(ClickEvent clickEvent) {
              if(saveHandler!=null){
                  saveHandler.onFire(mysavedObject); 
              }               
          }
       });
```

}

So here is what to do in your EntryPoint

```
 public class Main implements EntryPoint {

       ....
       Registration registration =new Registration();
       registration.addSaveHandler(new SuperPuperHandler<MySavedObject>(){
          public void onFire(MySavedObject t){
              // here is saved objects in registration form
          }
        });

}
```

Comment: it works thanks, but is there a better way to getting information. I mean i want to create a website and at main page there will be a registration form, if user fills this form and clicks register, Registration composite will be remove and another composite call it userPanel will be added. At userPanel there will be this users filled informations. sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern.  Your Registration component must have some way of adding a listener to handle the event of "the user pressed the button".

**Hand-made**

The simplest way is simply defining by yourself:

```
interface ClickListener {
  onButtonClicked(...); // use params if you want
}
```

and your Registration component offer a way to set the listener:

```
void addClickListener(ClickListener l) {
   this.listener = l;
}
```

then when the button is clicked you simple call your listener (interface)

```
...
if (listener != null)
   listener.onButtonClicked(...); // pass arguments if you want
...
```

your EntryPoint must register some listener:

```
Registration r = ...
r.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
   public void onButtonClicked(...) {
      // do what you need
   }
}
```

**Using GWT events**

In this case you should define a class for the event, and register handlers in a given way but it could be overkill. If I find the documentation about it. I'll add it to this answer.